# Allow only a decimal point after an input of three digits in a textbox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do I allow only a decimal point after an input of three digits in a textbox in VB.NET?

Let's say I inputed "123" after that I can only put a decimal else it wont allow any other input. So the result would be "123."

```
    Dim KeyAscii As Integer
    KeyAscii = Asc(myE.KeyChar)

    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case Asc("0") To Asc("9"), Asc(ControlChars.Back)

            myE.Handled = False
        Case Asc(".")

            If InStr(myTextbox.Text, ".") = 0 Then
                myE.Handled = False
            Else : myE.Handled = True
            End If

        Case myE.KeyChar = Chr(127)
            myE.Handled = False
        Case Else
            myE.Handled = True
    End Select
```

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: it's for a windows app. Using vb.net in visual studio

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow user to enter only numbers in a textbox in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413708/how-to-allow-user-to-enter-only-numbers-in-a-textbox-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms you could accomplish this by using the TextChanged-Event of the Textbox and RegularExpressions:

Example:

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions



Public Class Form1

   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
      '** Regex Pattern
      Dim pattern As String = "^(([0-9]{1,3})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.){1,1}([0-9]){0,3}))$"
      '** Copy of the Textbox Content
      Dim strText As String = TextBox1.Text
      '** Remove chars at the end of the string until the Textbox is empty or the contained chars are valid
      While Not Regex.IsMatch(strText, pattern) AndAlso Not strText = ""
         strText = strText.Substring(0, strText.Length - 1)
      End While
      '** Set the new text
      TextBox1.Text = strText
      '** Set the caret to the end of the string in the textbox
      TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
   End Sub
End Class
```

This example lets you write  `123`, `345.`, `12.`, `123.1`, `123.123` and so on...

To improve the number of digits before or after the decimal you can edit the `{0,3}` in the pattern (The first 2 times are for the digits before the decimal and the third time for the digits after the decimal). Just set instead of 3 the number of digits you like (or replace it with a `*` or `{0,}` for unlimited)

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 1:**

- Changed pattern from `"^[0-9]{0,3}(\.){0,1}$"` to `"^(([0-9]{1,3})|([0-9]{1,3}(\.){1,1}([0-9]){0,3}))$"` to allow digits after the decimal
- Corrected the While Loop Condition from `Textbox1.Text = ""` to `strText = ""`

Comment: This is great! but I also need it to input two or three more digits after the decimal point...

Comment: @Kurusu: In your question you said "How do I allow only a decimal point after an input of three digits". But now you say that it must be possible to enter more digits after the decimal point. So your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
Select Case myE.KeyChar
    Case "0"c To "9"c, "."c
        myE.Handled = InStr(myTextbox.Text, ".") > 0
    Case ControlChars.Back, Convert.ToChar(127)
        myE.Handled = False
    Case Else
        myE.Handled = True
End Select
```

Note: There is no point in converting the KeyChar to Integer and then use Asc() to compare.

**EDIT**: According to your comment the decimal point must be placed after the third digit and 2 or 3 more digits can follow.

```
Select Case myE.KeyChar
    Case "0"c To "9"c
        myE.Handled = myTextbox.Text.Length = 3 OrElse myTextbox.Text.Length >= 7
    Case "."c
        myE.Handled = myTextbox.Text.Length <> 3
    Case ControlChars.Back, Convert.ToChar(127)
        myE.Handled = False
    Case Else
        myE.Handled = True
End Select
```