# VB.NET: How to validate a textbox to not allow decimal values?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, decimal

I would like to know how i can validate a textbox to not allow any decimal values?

Comment: You'd better state if you are developing windform application and what the .net version it is

Comment: @SimonWang yes it is a windows application and vb 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution i got from this link ( [How to allow user to enter only numbers in a textbox in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413708/how-to-allow-user-to-enter-only-numbers-in-a-textbox-in-vb-net) )

```
   Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48) _
              Or (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
            e.Handled = True
    End If
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
            e.Handled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event and use the [`IsNumeric`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1.aspx) Function to trap the numeric keys.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)

Since handling the KeyPress can cause problem with delete/backspace/copy/paste/...