# Specifying data type on windows form textfield

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am a beginner in Visual Studio ( 2010 ) and I want to accept some data from form to backend as say Integer or any other class's object instead of getting in the headache of manually making the conversion(which I will have to learn if its not possible).

Textbox1.Text always returns String while I want it as Textbox1.ClassName to kind of get automatic conversion.

is it possible ?

Comment: one thing you can do is limit user input as specified here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413708/how-to-allow-user-to-enter-only-numbers-in-a-textbox-in-vb-net however it will still be a string, so you need to do the conversions yourself.

Comment: also, here's a great comprehensive article on input. http://www.rhyous.com/2010/06/18/how-to-limit-or-prevent-characters-in-a-textbox-in-csharp/

Comment: @Jeremy thank you Jeermy but its not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use conversion, you have no choice. What you can do is extention on the textbox and write your converter in it. Most likely passing a default value in case the conversion fails

Something like :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int TextAsInt(this TextBox txt, int defaultValue)
    {
        var result = 0;

        if (!Int32.TryParse(txt.Text, out result))
        {
            result = defaultValue;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like so :

```
int result = Textbox1.TextAsInt(50);
```

if the conversion fail the value returned would be 50

Now that said, the most intelligent way to make an extension like this reusable is to extend the string object and not the textbox. So it would be called on the `Textbox1.Text.TextAsInt(50);` instead.

Comment: I'd use `public static int TextAsInt(this TextBoxBase control, int default = 0)` and for validation purposes there could be method returning bool.

Comment: For that i would rather use an override as opposed to an optional.

Comment: @Franck its easy to convert from String to Integer but difficult to convert it into any object. Though, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Rorschach your comment doesn't really make sense because in .NET, "everything is an object". Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Jeremy its so in all object oriented languages, I meant it needs to be converted into and from a specified class object. I get the point that its not possible, as Franck has suggested.

Comment: @Rorschach unless you return the type object and cast it when needed. That would be more object oriented bu you need to know the type to cast later on so it come back being specific. You are much better writing down your own convert when they don't exist (or extend them for easier use / cleaner code)

Answer (score 1):

In winforms common practice is to *enhance* controls by making own, here is something I've used (cut version):

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int AsInt
    {
        get
        {
            int result;
            int.TryParse(Text, out result);
            return result;
        }
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool IsIntOk
    {
        get
        {
            int result;
            return int.TryParse(Text, out result);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        ForeColor = IsIntOk ? SystemColors.WindowText : Color.Red;
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```